# Google Cloud Platform limit the pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have a budget X$, and I want to deploy my service in GCP, but I'm afraid to exceed this budget, is there any way to set the max that I will pay (X$) in case my services uses more than X$ resources.

I never used GCP, I want to decide now if I use it or not based on the answers I'll get.

Comment: You can set billing alerts to warn you, but you cannot set a hard spending limit. I am not aware of any cloud vendor that provides that feature.

Comment: @john-hanley is correct and he makes an important point. You can set billing alerts **but** it is a warning only and you may still exceed this value. Various services provide mechanisms to limit scaling (which is one dimension that can cause runaway pricing). See [accepted payment methods](https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/9001356?hl=en&ref_topic=9023854#allowed-methods). The only provider I've seen that permits prepaid credits is [Fly](https://community.fly.io/t/buy-prepaid-credits-without-a-credit-card/5243/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google doesn't offer it out of the box.

The work around is to create alerts and then trigger custom code (like a cloud function) to shut down your project or disable billing. **Note that you still run the risk of exceeding your budget since the alert might only get sent after you've already passed your budget.**

Find links below

1. [Google's own documentation to disable billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage) which in turn will shut down your project
2. An [implementation](https://github.com/Cyclenerd/poweroff-google-cloud-cap-billing) of the above (previous bullet point) from someone on Github
3. A [blog article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-avoid-a-surprise-bill-on-a-google-app-engine-project/) from us on how to shut down your Google App Engine app when you exceed your budget (or get close to your budget)